# kendo ui always show tooltip on top for pie chart angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I have created a pie chart using kendoui referring to below link on telerik :-

https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/pie-charts/angular

> I tried to show tooltip on pie chart created which will always show
>   without hover on pie chart.

I have referred below pages but not found any solution :-

1. https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/line-charts/local-data-binding
2. [Kendo UI Chart - Want tooltip to always show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30554135/kendo-ui-chart-want-tooltip-to-always-show)
3. http://dojo.telerik.com/@Iliana/OnINu
4. [Kendo-ui tooltip in Angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28164886/kendo-ui-tooltip-in-angularjs/28886539#28886539)

My code is below :-

```html
<!-- Pie chart -->
<div class="demo-section k-content" ng-if="widget.id === 'pie'" id="widgetPie">
    <div id="pieWrapper">
        <div kendo-chart
            k-rebind="firmwareDevices"
            k-title="{ text: 'SLC Firmware Distribution', position: 'top' }"
            k-series-defaults="{ type: 'pie', labels: { visible: true }}"
            k-series="[{
                            field: 'doc_count',
                            name: 'SLC',
                            categoryField: 'key',
                            padding: 0,
                            color: '#b8b8b8'
                        }]"
            k-data-source="deviceObject"
            k-series-hover="onSeriesHover"
            k-series-colors="['#66b3ff', '#b2d9ff']"
            k-tooltip="{ visible: true, template: '#= category # device_count: #= value #' }"
            k-legend = "{ position: 'left' }",
            style="height: 270px; width:450px;"
            id="ltxPie">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please have a look here https://www.telerik.com/forums/tooltip-at-top-of-chart-div

Comment: @AlexisToby I have mentioned this link above you shared but what option should I use from that link to resolve my probem ? because my 3rd link in question is same as provided by you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to the demo example below:

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/line-charts/local-data-binding

Try to set k-series-defaults as follows :-

```html
 k-series-defaults="{ type: 'pie', 
                      labels: {
                          visible: true,
                          format: '{0}%',
                          background: 'transparent'
                      }
                     }"
```